# Is it possible to access File Provider of another iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, foundation

I'm developing an app that needs to interact with other apps (that are developed by other persons). In order to do that, I wanted to use their [File Provider](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider) to read and write from that.

I know the group they're using, but I don't know the `URL` of the File Provider. I need a way to copy some files programmatically.

[image: What I'm trying to do]

I tried:

```
let provider = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.app.ish.iSH")
```

But it just doesn't work because I don't have the App Group in my App Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iOS apps are sandboxed partly to specifically prevent this kind of thing from happening. Typically we use inter application URLs to communicate between apps. On a standard (non-jailbroken) device I don't believe there's  way to read another application's files when you didn't develop that other app and can't control the app group

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer. I'll see with the developer if they can implement drag and drop as a replacement of the original solution.

Comment: You can communicate with other apps using [NSFileProviderService](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfileproviderservice#2934440).